# How to get a property from a array

Tags: json, linux, csv, jq

i want to convert a json File like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 727,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "number": "727",
    "order_key": "wc_order_58d2d042d1d",
    "created_via": "rest-api",
    "version": "3.0.0",
    "status": "processing",
    "currency": "USD",
    "date_created": "2017-03-22T16:28:02",
    "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:28:02",
    "date_modified": "2017-03-22T16:28:08",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:28:08",
    "discount_total": "0.00",
    "discount_tax": "0.00",
    "shipping_total": "10.00",
    "shipping_tax": "0.00",
    "cart_tax": "1.35",
    "total": "29.35",
    "total_tax": "1.35",
    "prices_include_tax": false,
    "customer_id": 0,
    "customer_ip_address": "",
    "customer_user_agent": "",
    "customer_note": "",
    "billing": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "company": "",
```

and i want just some properties like: id, satus, total and from billing first_name.

How do i geht the first name from billing array?

this does not work?
-Thanks

i tried this:

```
jq -r map({id,number,date_created,status,.billing[].first_name}) | (first | keys_unsorted) as $keys | map([to_entries[] | .value]) as $rows | $keys,$rows[] | @csv
```

Comment: `.billing` is an object, so `.billing.first_name` will do what you want. Use something like `bfn: .billing.first_name` to give it a field name in your new object.

Comment: I tried: .billing.first_name, .billing[].first_name, billing.first_name

Comment: I tried: .billing.first_name, .billing[].first_name, billing_first_name
But without succeess. I get compile error

Comment: `map({id,number,date_created,status,bfn:.billing.first_name}) | …`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`{}` Object Construction](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D) filter to map the array elements to new objects. If key in the input and output are identical, you can use the shorthand form `{key}`, which is equivalent to `{key: .key}`.

The first_name of the nested object can be accessed with the [.foo Object Identifier-Index](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo,.foo.bar) filter:

```
map({id, status, total, first_name: .billing.first_name})
```